# How to add opencv to turbo c++?

Tags: opencv, turbo-c++

I need to work with opencv library using turbo c++. I've downloaded opencv and installed turbo c++, but how to integrate both of them

Comment: why do you think you want to use turbo c++?

Comment: Then why not use a modern IDE like CodeBlocks or VC++ Express?

Comment: The instructions given in openframeworks did not help me out. Can you give a better instruction for uing code block with open framework in windows

Answer (score 0):

Open CV uses .dll files and which are not supported by turbo c++ 
and many other issues like 16 bit etc. Hence it is not possible.I also tried for using open GL but it did not worked in turbo c++.
Download Dev c++ instead .Its just 9 MB download.
use the link to downlaod:[Dev Cpp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dev-cpp/files/Binaries/Dev-C%2B%2B%204.9.9.2/devcpp-4.9.9.2_setup.exe/download?use_mirror=nchc)